# Message Passing between sender and receiver

Tags: linux

In message-passing (producer-consumer) a Blocking send happens when the sending process is blocked until the message is received by the receiving process or by the mailbox.

A Blocking receive instead is when the receiver blocks until a message is available.

**The solution to the producer–consumer problem becomes trivial when we use blocking send() and receive() statements.**

Why it becomes trivial ?

Comment: Because it synchronises the sender and receiver?

Comment: The book doesnt explain this

Answer (score 1):

The book ("Operating System Concepts" - Silberschatz, Galvin, Gagne) you appear to be quoting has this to say on the subject:

> Different combinations of send() and receive() are possible. When both send() and receive() are blocking, we have a rendezvous between the sender and the receiver. The solution to the producer-consumer problem becomes trivial when we use blocking send() and receive() statements. **The producer merely invokes the blocking send() call and waits until the message is delivered to either the receiver or the mailbox.** Likewise, when the consumer invokes receive(), it blocks until a message is available.

It seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: So, it synchronises the sender and receiver. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is: please try to implement a solution to the consumer-producer problem where reading and writing are non-blocking.

If you do so, that is if you think about how to solve the problem with non-blocking read/write operations, you will quickly discover, that you need to do buffer management. Then you'll discover that in a concurrent situation you have to deal with reader/writer fairness etc. The problem gets multifaceted very quickly, with some of the sub-problems (fairness) having no obvious solution.